# Problem: In dataset i have data of country,state and city. Where some state and city name is 0.so,I want to replace "0" value of state with city name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

```
Cities = ['Acre','Ashdod','Ashqelon','Bat Yam','Beersheba','Bnei Brak','Caesarea','Dimona','Dor','Elat','Kefar Sava','Lod','Meron','Nahariyya','Nazareth','Netanya']

lst = []

for i in range(500):

    i = random.choice(Cities)
    print(i)
    lst.append(i)

Data.loc[(Data['country'] == 'Israel') & (Data['state'] == 0),'state'] = lst
```

I tried this method. In this code list some city of israel and generate 500 random value of it.
And apply condition to insert data in israel state location where data is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# mask data so you compute mask only once
mask = (Data['country'] == 'Israel') & (Data['state'] == 0)
# find the length
len_to_replace = len(Data[mask])
# replace
Data.loc[mask, 'state'] = [random.choice(Cities) for _ in range(len_to_replace)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the same data in the City column?

Comment: sure it is... just copyData.loc[mask, 'City'] = Data[mask]['state'].tolist() or via a separate function,, returning a twice: def a(): a=random.choice(Cities); return a, a; and then Data.loc[mask, ['state', 'City']] = [a() for _ in range(len_to_replace)]

Comment: I want to add data of the same city name where state = 0.

Comment: Data.loc[mask, 'state'] = Data.loc[mask, 'City']